# Create Dummies for Multiple Columns on Unique Value in a Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, dummy-variable

I have a Dataframe as mentioned below, I have multiple categories for CTI and RESOLUTION and the goal is to create dummy variables for the CTI and RESOLUTION  Categories and for the categories that do not have an entry for this specific account.

```
       ACCOUNT  |   CTI       |      RESOLUTION
        59737001    Data:HI         Customer Owned Issue / Customer Equipment
        59737001    Data:HI         Repaired / Replaced Drop Underground
        13847688    Data:OK         Not Repaired
```

My expected output is

```
    ACCOUNT  |  CTI_Data:HI | CTI_DATA:OK| RESOLUTION_Customer Owned... | RESOLUTION_Repaired/Repla.... | RESOLUTION_Not Repaired
     59737001      1         0                  1                          1                         0
```

I know `pd.get_dummies()` works for getting the dummies for multiple categories but my case is different.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: In your expected output, where is the `CTI_Data:HFC:CBI` coming from? the original data you show here doesn't have anything with HFC:CBI in it.

Comment: @scotscotmcc Apologies I fixed that.

Comment: Also, is that first column an index and you've just given us a few entries that aren't in order? Is that what the 2, 25012, and 213 are? Or are those part of the account that is 8 characters long?

Comment: @scotscotmcc Yeah that is just the index.

Comment: @scotscotmcc I removed the indexes so that there is no confusion in understanding the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can get this by using both `pd.get_dummies()` and `df.groupby().any()`. The `groupby().any()` will return TRUE/FALSE, and so you end that with converting to `int`

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['CTI','RESOLUTION']) # df is what you have in your first example. Putting in the columns here restricts dummies to just those columns.
df2.groupby('ACCOUNT').any().astype(int)
```

Comment: It won't work because it also creates dummies for the Account this way and the groupby fails

Comment: I think I probably have slightly different columns from you since we goofed around with the index stuff at the beginning, taking it out and changing it and all. You should be able to handle this by putting in the `columns` parameter in `get_dummies()`. I'm updating the code above now.